# display:none breaking formatting when a html page is loaded inside the div through ajax?

Tags: javascript, css

I've a div that uses `display:none` which hides the element without breaking any page formatting/layout. However, if I get another html page using ajax and set the innerhtml of that div using jQuery during document.ready() event, then the formatting breaks.

**Please note that if you comment out the code inside ** **, the formatting doesn't break.**

Firebug doesn't show any JS errors.

Here's the ajax and setting the content code:

```
        var htmlStuff;
        $.ajax({
          url: "temp.html",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
               htmlStuff= html;
               **$('#myDiv').html(htmlStuff);**
          }
        });
```

Here is the div:

```
<div id = "myDiv" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: How do you do this? Show us some code.

Comment: @NicklasNygren I've edited my post to include some code.

Comment: Have you seen scott's answer? Might that be the case? That is, is temp.html a full html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting the full content of the "temp.html" file and putting that in your div.

If "temp.html" contains a complete HTML document (including `html`, `head` and `body` elements), this will make the HTML on the current page invalid, and could cause the problem you're seeing.

In your javascript, you might need to search for the body of "temp.html", and only insert the content of the body ensuring you exclude the `<body>` and `</body>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting a div from `display:none;` and then changing it to a block value that will break your layout as `display:none;` does not consume space within a html layout.

Comment: No, I don't change it to block or anything - it stays the same. Unless you're talking about the block setting of some div INSIDE the div in question.